# Is there a define like __APPLE__ for Objective C/C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I got a little C++ helper file which has some support functions for std::strings. As I use it in ".cpp" files and in ".mm" files, I want to add some Objective C++ helper functions. Now I search for a define like:

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#ifdef __I_AM_INCLUDED_IN_A_MM_FILE__
// define some Objective C++ code here
#endif
#endif
```

Is there a define? Is there a list of XCode defines?

Comment: It's exacly `#ifdef __APPLE__`. And it has nothing to do with Xcode -- it's a constant intrinsically defined by `clang`.

Comment: No. `__APPLE__` is defined in ".cpp" and in ".mm" and ".m" files.

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by that?

Comment: I search for a define which is only set in "Objective C" language files. So only in ".mm" files not in ".cpp" files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`__OBJC__` and `__OBJC2__` are defined when compiling a .mm file.

For future reference you can test for things like this as follows:

```
$ clang -dM -E foo.mm > mm.txt
$ clang -dM -E foo.cpp > cpp.txt
$ sdiff -s mm.txt cpp.txt
#define IBAction void)__attribute__((ibaction)                <
#define IBOutlet __attribute__((iboutlet))                    <
#define IBOutletCollection(ClassName) __attribute__((iboutlet <
#define OBJC_ZEROCOST_EXCEPTIONS 1                            <
#define __NEXT_RUNTIME__ 1                                    <
#define __OBJC2__ 1                                           <
#define __OBJC__ 1                                            <
```

(note that foo.mm and foo.cpp are just empty files)

Comment: Is there a Apple Doc for XCode where that is described?

Comment: See latest edit for an empirical method to find this type of information.

Comment: awesome. exact hit :-)